# What does "well you" after a comma mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> Your body size doesn't make you well, well you!

What does “*well you*” mean in this sentence?

Comment: Looks like gibbberish from a non-native speaker to me.

Comment: It doesn't look like non-native English to me.  It looks like each *well* is a filler word.  "Your body size doesn't make you you!"  It's probably hard to tell because of how the commas were used (or not used).

Comment: Can you give the conversational context, the surrounding sentences, or at least a link to the original? IT's hard to tell without that.

Comment: @snailboat: What are we doing here? Solving riddles? I could put up with the pun-like use of ***you*** in two different ways here. I could even put up with ***well*** as a "filler", but pointlessly repeating it here just to construct a confusing text fragment doesn't seem like a useful exercise. Anyway, my closevote is for *Unclear what you're asking*. But if we'd been supplied with enough context (ideally, including an audio file of the words as actually spoken) and it turned out your interpretation is correct, I'd probably think the question was *Too Basic*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It didn't seem like a riddle to me.  The meaning was clear.  (It doesn't really matter to me whether you close it or not.  It's your site, not mine.  But the meaning was apparent, so I left a comment.)

Comment: @snailboat: It's no more my site than it is yours. But I do have *some* opinions about what should and shouldn't be considered useful questions here (most but not all of which are endorsed by the FAQ).

Comment: Tim's answer "Size doesn't make you you" makes the most sense - I was answering a question on a quiz and the phase was one of the choices of what advice would you give to someone.  Thanks Tim

Comment: Hi @Kris, thanks for visiting ELU. Your question looks like one that could be easily answered if you asked an English teacher or a friend who spoke English fluently. This site is not a substitute for formal English lessons or practicing with a friend, which makes this question off-topic. If you have tried to answer it using several resources, then please [edit] this to explain how you have tried to answer it yourself and why you're still unsure.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's an extra "well". A single *well* there, set off by commas, is an interjection, a rhetorical strategy of a speaker who is here acknowledging or conceding that the predicate may sound tautological:

**Your body size doesn't make you, well, you!**

The sentence means that it would be reductive to think the size of your body is your "essence".  Body size is a mere attribute or property.

Size doesn't make you you.

Size is not the causal principle or essence, the core "thing" that causes you to be who you are.

Comment: Thanks Tim - your explanation makes sense. I come across so many grammatical errors and see them immediately except for this one - must have been a mental block or a senior's moment. Have a good day.

Comment: Mari-Lou A:  Yes Tim Romano's answer helped me.  I did not know that I should accept his answer, how do I do that?  I'm new to the site.  Thanks.

Comment: @Kris: Glad to be of some help.